# Obtain DLFileEntry with view permission

Tags: java, sql, permissions, liferay

Is there a way to obtain a DLFileEntries from a DB, without testing all of them with a permission checker? Also is there a way to combine it with SQL Query? What I need to do, is to obtain every DLFileEntry, that user can VIEW, matching the SQL Query.

Thanks in advance.